# Casting using System.Type - c#

Tags: c#, casting

Is it possible to cast an object to a desired type using `System.Type?` as the reference?

I had a search and the general consensus was no, although I was hoping there may be some aids introduced in C# 4.0 that could help me.

I.e. the below will not work, but the pseudocode is what I would like.

```
object o = null;
var t = typeof(string);
...
string foo = (t)o;
```

Edit: I need use `XmlSerializer` to reconstruct / deserialize to the type stored in `t`

Comment: What would you expect the compile-time type of `foo` to be? What are you really trying to achieve? Explaining the bigger picture would help a lot.

Comment: If you try to write a sample usage, you'll see that your question is meaningless.

Comment: Even for the XmlSerializer, I fail to see why you would need this cast. Can you add a code showing what you're trying to do, even if this code doesn't work?

Answer (score 26):

Have a look at:

```
var foo = Convert.ChangeType(o, typeof(string))
```

Comment: But `Convert.ChangeType` still returns the `object` type, i.e. it doesn't solve the problem?!

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't make sense.

Casting doesn't *change* an object at all; it just lets you use the object as the given type **at compile-time**.
If you don't know what type you're casting it to *at compile-time*, the cast is useless, since it wouldn't let you do anything with the casted expression.

Comment: Actually it can change an object, if it implements an 'explicit' operator.

Comment: @KooKiz: Not at run-time.  That will only happen if the compiler knows to call the operator.

Answer (score 1):

No need to cast. The object doesn't change, your type of references (variables) changes when "casting".

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like [System.ChangeType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx). This works if the type implement [IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx), and if it is convertible to the desired type ( of course this is not a cast )