# Enumerate specific type of members by a inherited constructor

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a menu for a console, and I have this code:

```
public class Option { /* Id, Name, & constructor */ }
public abstract class Menu {
    protected const int rawId = 0;
    protected Menu() {
        int i = 0;
        // CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Menu.Menu' because 'Menu.Menu' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'
        foreach (Option o in this) { o.Id = ++i; } // Assigns an id to each option in inherited menus
    }
}
public class MMain:Menu {
    Option OpenFile = new Option(rawId, "Open File");
    Option ExitProgram = new Option(rawId, "Terminate Program");
    public MMain():base() { }
}
int Prompt(/* menu to be displayed */) { /* List options; Return selected by id }
```

So that in the main program, I can do this:

```
switch (Prompt(/* MMain this case */)) {
    case MMain.OpenFile.Id: { /* Opens A File */ break; }
    case MMain.ExitProgram.Id: { /* Exits */ break; }
}
```

Problem is, `this` in `foreach` needs a `GetEnumerator` thing, which I failed to enumerate `Option`s from both the base and the inherited class. Lack of `Option` should return at least an empty object.

I'm avoiding:

1. string comparison with `switch` (hurts efficiency, so I introduced `id`)
2. use of `enum` (tried it, cannot be used as parameters for function, made a mess)
3. tailoring a function for each menu (hard to maintain, kills consistency)

Is there any way to accomplish this?

---

### Unsuccessful Approach with `enum` (bg info)

**Fine to ignore.** Included in case being asked to try `enum`, tried this:

```
public class MMain {
    public enum Option { OpenFile, ExitProgram /* and more */ }
    public static string NameOf(Option o) {
        return o switch {
            Option.OpenFile => "Open File",
            Option.ExitProgram => "Terminate Program",
            _ => throw new ArgumentException(InvMO)
        };
    }
    public static Option Prompt() {
        ListOptions(typeof(Option));
        /* return Choice(...); */
    }
    private static void ListOptions(Type t) {
        foreach (var option in Enum.GetValues(t)) {
            // CS1503: cannot convert from 'object' to 'Option'
            Console.WriteLine(NameOf(option));
            /* Also if casting like this: Console.WriteLine((t)NameOf(option))
               it will give CS0118: 't' is a variable but is used like a type */
        }
    }
}
```

and this:

```
    /* ... */
    public static Option Prompt() {
        Option opts;
        ListOptions(opts); // Unable to declare a function that inputs all types of enum
        /* ... */
```

So that in the main program:

```
switch (MMain.Prompt()) {
    case MMain.Option.OpenFile: { /* Opens A File */ break; }
    case MMain.Option.ExitProgram: { /* Exits */ break; }
}
```

### Credits

Guidance of my code as follows:

1. [Associating enums with strings in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1343517/20158640), source of the whole idea for replacing `enum`, really
2. [Constructor inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3873379/20158640)

For the `enum` approach:

3. [`class EnumLoop<Key> where Key : struct, IConvertible`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9113274), felt it was so close but eventually didn't work it out myself, therefore gave up `enum`
4. [`foreach (Suit suit in (Suit[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)))`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/105402), cannot pass `enum` hence cannot create `Option opt in (Option[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Option)))`
5. [Creating variable with `System.Type`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8448397/20158640) (Passing `typeof(Option)` to a function, to create `Option opt` in the function, unable to work it out too)

Comment: In the enum attempt, what was your reason for making `ListOptions` take the type as a parameter? Are you planning to define different types of options?

Comment: Why not just add an abstract `Options` property that inheritors implement (possibly dynamic using reflection) that returns the `Option` properties it has? I admit I'm not understanding what the `Enum` gives you.

Comment: I'm making different `Option`s for each menu. `enum` avoids the use of magic numbers, and by declaring a class of `string` it would kill efficiency when do case switching. Yet I'm avoiding `enum` partly because of [this blog](https://volaresoftware.com/en/technical-posts/stop-wasting-time-with-enums-in-c) and partly because casting `enum` makes the code clumsy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question very well, but this problem could be worked around using reflections, or, a much easier approach, working as a list of options within the menu, like this:

```
using static MMain;

var main = new MMain();
switch ((MMainOptions)main.Prompt())
{
    case MMainOptions.OpenFile:
        Console.WriteLine($"Chosen option: Open file");
        break;
    case MMainOptions.TerminateProgram:
        Console.WriteLine($"Chosen option: Terminate program");
        break;
}

Console.ReadKey();

public class Option
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Option(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
    public Option() { }
}
public abstract class Menu
{
    protected List<Option> Options { get; set; }
    protected Menu()
    {
        Options = new List<Option>();
    }

    public int Prompt()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0,2}{1,2}", "Id", "Name");
        foreach (var option in Options)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,2}{1,2}", option.Id, , option.Name);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Type id:");
        var result = Console.ReadLine();
        return Convert.ToInt32(result);
    }
}
public class MMain : Menu
{
    public enum MMainOptions
    {
        OpenFile = 1,
        TerminateProgram = 2
    }
    public MMain() : base()
    {
        Options.Add(new Option((int)MMainOptions.OpenFile, "Open File"));
        Options.Add(new Option((int)MMainOptions.TerminateProgram, "Terminate Program"));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is the way. You get the enumerability that's baked into `List<T>`, and don't lose the type safety of the `Enum`.